# Enabling multiple MSI in PCI driver with different IRQ handlers

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, interrupt, pci

Currently i have a requirement to support MSI with 2 vectors on my PCI device. Each vector needs to have a different handler routine. HW document says the following

vector 0 is for temperature sensor

vector 1 is for power sensor

Below is the driver code i am following.
1. First enable two vectors using pci_enable_msi_block(pdev, 2)
2. Next assign interrupt handlers using request_irq(two different irq, two diff interrupt handlers).

```
int vecs = 2;
struct pci_dev *pdev = dev->pci_dev;
result = pci_enable_msi_block(pdev, vecs);
```

Here result is zero which says call succeeded in enabling two vectors.

Questions i have is:

1. HW document says vector 0, i hope this is not the vector 0 of OS right? In any case i can't get vector 0 in OS.
2. Difficult problem i am facing is when i do request_irq() for first irq, how do i say to OS that i need to map this request to vector 0 of HW? Consecutively for second irq, how do i map t vector 1 of HW?

Answer (score 2):

pci_enable_msi_block:

If 2 MSI messages are requested using this function and if the function call returns 0, then 2 MSI messages are allocated for the device and `pdev->irq` is updated to the lowest of the interrupts assigned to the device.

So `pdev->irq` and `pdev->irq+1` are the new interrupts assigned to the device. You can now register two interrupt handlers:

```
request_irq(pdev->irq, handler1, ...)  
request_irq(pdev->irq+1, handler2, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

With MSI and MSI-X, the interrupt number(irq) is a CPU "vector". Message signaled interrupts allow the device to write a small amount of data to a special memory-mapped I/O address; the chipset then delivers the corresponding interrupt to a processor.

May be there are two different MSI interrupt data that can be written to a MSI address. Its like your hardware supports 2 MSI (one for Temperature Sensor and one for Power Sensor). So when you issue `pci_enable_msi_block(pdev, 2);`, the interrupt will be asserted by the chipset to the processor whenever any of the two MSI data is written to that special memory-mapped I/O address (MSI address).
After the call to `pci_enable_msi_block(pdev, 2);` ,you can request two irqs through `request_irq(pdev->irq, handler, flags....)` and  `request_irq(pdev->irq + 1, handler, flags....)`. So whenever the MSI data is written to the MSI address, `pdev->irq` or `pdev->irq + 1` will be asserted depending on which sensor sent the MSI and the corresponding handler will be invoked.

This two MSI data can be configured into the hardware's MSI data register.